# Javascript function to convert string and keywords to inner HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This function recieves a char array, and converts it into a string.
It then looks for keywords in the string, formats them and send the string back with html tags to be converted to html. This works, but is there a better way to write this?

```
function formatCode(data){    
     var keywords = ["public", "class", "static", "void", "int", "double"];
     var retVal= data.join("");
     var dataArray = retVal.split(" ");
     var temp = "";

     for( var i=0; i<dataArray.length; i++ ) {
        temp = temp + (i+1) + ": " + dataArray[i] + "\n";
       }
    retVal = "";
    for( var i=0; i<dataArray.length; i++ ) {
        var idx = -1;
        var temp = "";

        for( var j=0; j<keywords.length; j++ ) {
            if( dataArray[i].includes(keywords[j]))
                idx = j;
        }
            if( idx >= 0 ) {
              var temp = "";
              idx = dataArray[i].indexOf(keywords[idx]);
              var noStyle = false;
              for( var j=0; j<idx; j++ )
              {
                temp += dataArray[i].charAt(j);
                if( (dataArray[i].charAt(j) >= 'a' && dataArray[i].charAt(j) <= 'z') ||
                (dataArray[i].charAt(j) >= 'A' && dataArray[i].charAt(j) <= 'Z') ) 
                    noStyle = true;  

            }
            if( !noStyle ) {
                temp += "<span class=\"keyword\">"; 
            }
            temp += dataArray[i].substring(idx);
            if( !noStyle ) {
                temp += "</span>";              
            }
            retVal += temp;
        }
        else {
            retVal += "" + dataArray[i];
        }
        retVal += " ";
    }   
    data = "" + retVal;
    retVal = "";
    for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
        if(data.charAt(i) == '\n')
            retVal+='</br>';
        else if(data.charAt(i) == '\t')
            retVal+='&emsp;';
        else
          retVal += data.charAt(i);
        }

    return retVal;
}
```

Comment: at least format it properly...

Comment: Can you show us an example of how **data** looks like? So that we can play with it and see what we can do.

Comment: besides you should put this on codereview rather than here since your code is working

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the code is working.  [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) would be more appropriate.

Comment: Sorry. I'm new to this. I'll ask there then